# instance member "baseURL" cannot be used on type "URL"

Tags: swift

On the fifth line i m getting the error that " instance member "baseURL" cannot be used on type "URL". Someone please help me solve this error.

```
func getFileURL() -> URL {
    let fileName = (imagePath! as NSString).lastPathComponent
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let pathArray:[String] = [dirPath, fileName]
    let fileURL = URL.baseURL(withPathComponents: pathArray)
    return fileURL!
}
let fileURL = URL.baseURL(withPathComponents: pathArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `baseURL` on the class `URL`, not an actual instance of `URL`. It would be like trying to eat not an apple, but the word "apple". Try this instead:

```
func getFileURL() -> URL {
    let fileName = (imagePath! as NSString).lastPathComponent
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath, isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    return fileURL.baseURL!
}
```

EDIT: I'm not exactly sure about what you're trying to ask, so you may need to change `return fileURL.baseURL!` to `return fileURL`.

Comment: Then After You can use this file path as var url = URL(String : filePath)

Comment: @JAck I think you mean `URL(string: getFileURL())`, but wouldn't work (and is unnecessary) since the result is already a URL. See: `let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath, isDirectory: true)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
func getFileURL() -> String {
 var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/output/outPut.mov") // whatever filetype you want

return File Path
}
```